# cannot find request_irq(), irq.h or interrupt.h to use in a simple interrupt handler

Tags: ubuntu, interrupt, centos7, interrupt-handling, irq

I am trying to write a simple handler for interrupts from a GPIO port.  I have never tried to register an IRQ before, but see discussions on using request_irq and request_threaded_irq, but I cannot find header files containing these on my CentOS7 or Ubuntu 16.04 systems.  Sample code I have seen include linux/irq.h and linux/interrupt.h but neither appear on my system.  Do I need to install additional packages (RPMs etc) to use these?  I have tried searching for such a package for either CentOS or Ubuntu but have not found one.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answer to my question.  I need to install the package linux-headers-generic (or one specific to my kernel version).  I think it includes the headers that I need and I will need it anyway if I write a kernel module.